# How to use cURL to download a file from a website

Tags: curl

I am trying to use cURL on a Mac with OSX 10.10 (Yosemite) to download a large file from an web-based FTP site.  For whatever reason, Apple includes cURL but not wget, and I'd like to use it.  However the standard command of

```
 curl http://website.com/file.ext
```

prints some ASCII ridiculousness to the standard output and doesn't download the file.

Here is actually what I am trying to do:

```
curl http://cdna.eva.mpg.de/denisova/BAM/human/DNK02.bam
```

This is a very large file, however, so beware if you want to try it out.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

By default, curl prints the content to standard output. Probably, you are requesting a binary file, which is not printed correctly on standard output. You should specify the file name to be saved with the -o option:

```
curl http://cdna.eva.mpg.de/denisova/BAM/human/DNK02.bam -o DNK02.bam
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the above. (The -o option is the best )

You can use output redirection

```
curl URL > file.ext
```

Or use wget

```
wget URL
```

Again the -o in the other answer is preferred